# Pub/Sub - Push to API when STATE is ACTIVE on Enrollment

Tags: android, google-api, mdm, android-management-api

I have implemented to **PUSH** a **PUB/SUB** notification to my **POST API** with the device details on `ENROLLMENT`. But notification comes in while the device `STATE` is still `PROVISIONING`

Is there a way to get the notification only when the `STATE` is `ACTIVE` ? This would help us in getting IMEI of the device only after Enrollment is complete to add it into our DB.

1. My Policy contains absolutely nothing, so Policy is compliant.

```
{
  "name": "enterprises/LC023XXXX/policies/Policy_D-a26fead-4c03-b987-b5692e23ab19",
  "version": "18"
}
```

2. When I fetch Device Info, it's **ACTIVE** :

```
{
  "name": "enterprises/LC023XXX/devices/343ee9888eXXXXX",
  "managementMode": "PROFILE_OWNER",
  "state": "ACTIVE",
  "appliedState": "ACTIVE",
  "policyCompliant": true
}
```

3. But with **ENROLLMENT** status, `Pub/Sub` never sends with `State : ACTIVE` :

```
{
 "name": "enterprises/LC021mqgu0/devices/34aeb69ab34355aa",
 "managementMode": "PROFILE_OWNER",
 "state": "PROVISIONING",
 "enrollmentTime": "2020-06-14T10:20:01.713Z",
 "lastPolicySyncTime": "2020-06-14T10:20:01.716Z"
}
```

4. Here's how my `Enterprise` is configured :

```
{
  "name": "enterprises/LC02XXXXX",
  "enabledNotificationTypes": [
    "ENROLLMENT"
  ],
  "pubsubTopic": "projects/projectName/topics/enrollmentNotification"
}
```

I have tried with multiple `Enterprises` and none of the enterprises send me the expected `STATE - ACTIVE`

Any help on what's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

The STATE - ACTIVE notification will only be sent via status report so you have to set `enabledNotificationTypes` to also include `STATUS_REPORT`. You will receive this notification once the enrollment is completed and the device syncs the assigned policy.

Your enterprise should be configured as follows:

```
{ 
  "name": "enterprises/LC02XXXXX", 
  "enabledNotificationTypes": [ "ENROLLMENT","STATUS_REPORT" ], 
  "pubsubTopic": "projects/projectName/topics/enrollmentNotification" 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that in *```STATUS_REPORT```* we get the device is ```ACTIVE``` but it defeats the purpose of *```ENROLLMENT```* type notifications because that's what it's meant for and I've noticed it previously that it used to send and also people on Google EMM community have confirmed that it should give *```ACTIVE ENROLLMENT```* notification should come in.